# Ubuntu - gnuplot reread deselecting text

Tags: ubuntu, plot, gnuplot

I am running a simulation - a fluid dynamics problem - on my ubuntu partition, and whilst I am running it I want to be able to see how it is progressing so I have scripts to plot data using gnuplot. These look like so -

```
set term x11 1 noraise
set logscale y
set title "Residuals"
set ylabel 'Residual'
set xlabel 'Iteration'
plot "< cat log.simpleFoam | grep 'Solving for Ux' | cut -d' ' -f9 | tr -d ','" title 'Ux' with lines,\
"< cat log.simpleFoam | grep 'Solving for Uy' | cut -d' ' -f9 | tr -d ','" title 'Uy' with lines,\
"< cat log.simpleFoam | grep 'Solving for epsilon' | cut -d' ' -f9 | tr -d ','" title 'epsilon' with lines,\
"< cat log.simpleFoam | grep 'Solving for k' | cut -d' ' -f9 | tr -d ','" title 'k' with lines,\
"< cat log.simpleFoam | grep 'Solving for p' | cut -d' ' -f9 | tr -d ','" title 'p' with lines
pause 1
reread
```

The first line was a fix I found to stop the x11 plot window forcing itself to the front every time the graph is replotted, however I still have a problem which is making my life difficult: every time the plot is reread any text I have selected in any application is automatically deselected, which is making running these very difficult as I want to work on other things whilst they run.

Does anyone know of a reason why this is happening? Or have a fix for it?

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce your problem with these informations. Does the same happen with the short script `set terminal x11 1 noraise; i = 1; plot i*x; while (1) { i = i+1; replot; pause 1;}`? With this script I don't have any problems on Debian with gnuplot 4.6.4. Maybe it also depends on your window manager settings?

Comment: Yes same happens with this script, I'm running gnuplot 4.6.1 I believe, perhaps it's been a recent bugfix. I will try the solution @andyras posted

Comment: Could you post information about which version of Ubuntu, which window manager/desktop environment you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different terminal (pdf, eps, etc.) and keep the output open in evince, which refreshes automatically.  This worked for me when I used to work in Ubuntu.

```
set term pdfcairo
set output 'dynamics.pdf'
...
```

As for why this is happening: my thought is that if you are running a very new version of Ubuntu, X may not be playing nice with Mir.  Otherwise it's not very clear to me; it may be worth filing as a bug report.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go. I'd remove the reread command then? Or keep it in?

I'm quite new to linux, never needed to use it before, but the software I'm using for my project doesn't run on OS X.

Ok I'll submit it when I get a chance.

Comment: I would follow a form like @Christoph's, using a while loop and the `replot` command to keep it plotting.

Comment: 'Unable to open document - PDF document is damaged'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, and eventually discovered that the "wxt" terminal works almost identically, but does not have this problem.

Here is an example of the script I ended up using:

```
set term wxt noraise
while (1) {

    # perform the plot here...

    pause 1
}
```